# Open app with (deep-) link containing path and query-parameter

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

These three urls are given:

```
1) https://example.com

2) https://example.com/app

3) https://example.com/app?param=hello
```

Assumed that i receive a mail in the gmail-app with these three links, I need the following behaviour:

```
1) Should not open the app

2) Should open the app

3) Should open the app and extract the parameter's value
```

What i have achieved so far:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/app"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This snippet is working fine for the cases `1)` and `2)`: The first url is not opened in the app, the second one is. But the third link sadly i not opened by the app.

I also tried some different variations with `path`, `pathPrefix` and `pathPattern`, but i had no luck achieving all three given behaviours.

So I need your help guys, can you provide a snippet that meets the given requirements or some hints I can test?

**Update:**

Changing `android:pathPrefix` to `android:pathPattern` works now fine: The system's intent chooser is only shown for cases `2)` and `3)`, case `1)` opens the browser directly.

**but**

what I want to achieve additionally is to check for a specific parameter before entering the app or triggering the intent chooser. This should only happen when the parameter `param` holds the value `hello` and not `goodbye`. Is this possible with some kind of regular expression inside the `pathPattern`-attribute?

Comment: Have you used jetpack navigation in this?

Comment: @RjzSatvara no i haven't

Comment: Can you share the solution please for case 3 @JU5T1C3

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for the last question posted yet?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this solution help you in solving the task.

**Manifest.xml**

> Don't include `android:pathPrefix="/app"`in **Manifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="example.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

> In YourActivity.kt check the Intent data to perform further action.
>
> **Note:** The code is written in Kotlin

```
    val action = intent.action
    val data = intent.dataString
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == action && data != null) {
        if (data.equals("http://example.com")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "contains only URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (data.contains("http://example.com/") && !data.contains("?")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "contains URL with pathPrefix", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else if (data.contains("http://example.com/") && data.contains("?")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "contains URL with data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Intent from Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: but that means, that the app is always opened, even when when the url `https://example.com` is not supposed to trigger the intent chosser and display my app as an opening option

Comment: Did you find solution?